# PowerShell case sensitive alphabet character order?

Tags: powershell, string-comparison, case-sensitive

I’ve programmed quite a bit in other languages but I’m fairly new to PowerShell. I’m aware of the case sensitive versions of the comparison operators but I’m nervous about some results..

I assumed that PowerShell used ASCII (Unicode) values when doing string comparisons so I expected

```
"abc" -clt "ABC"
```

to result in **False** – but it didn’t

This makes some intuitive sense (lower must be smaller than upper – right?) but it doesn’t make sense from an ASCII point of view. Has this just been reversed for the Roman alphabet characters – or are there more surprises waiting for me?

Ex

```
"#$%" -clt ")*+"
```

works as expected (i.e. **True**).

**EDIT** - my original question includes a double negative that might be confusing people. Here are some more examples to help clarify:

```
PS> 'A' -clt 'a'
False

PS> 'a' -clt 'A'
True

P> 'A' -cgt 'a'
True

P> 'a' -cgt 'A'
False
```

Comment: I'm uncertain why `-clt` is performing that way, but `-lt` when used on strings will use the correct code points.

Comment: When you pick an operator with explicit casing, you're also telling PowerShell to use the string-specific overload for the operator, and they all default to lexicographic/alphabetic order. By convention, uppercase letters precede their lowercase equivalents when sorting alphabetically :)

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen That sounds like an answer

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen - but in this case UPPERCASE don't precede lowercase - which is why I'm asking.

I probably shouldn't have used a double negative in my question.

"ABC" -clt "abc" is False
"abc" -clt "ABC" is True

Comment: @TheIncorrigible1 - -lt is case insensitive.

"abc" -lt "ABC" is false
"ABC" -lt "abc" is also false - because they are actually equivalent

Comment: Uppercase letters also precede lowercase letters in ASCII value - so the "lexicographic/alphabetic" order normally follows this - but the operator in question does not work this way - hence my confusion and the source of the question -- it's possible it's related to my Windows installation (region settings, etc.)

Answer (score 2):

> I assumed that PowerShell used ASCII (Unicode) values when doing string comparisons

It does not :)

The string-specific overloads for the comparison operators in PowerShell all operate on *alphabetical order*, and that also means giving precedence to upper-case letters over their lower-case equivalents.

---

Another way to think of it: if you were a librarian and had to index books on the same subject by two authors styling themselves as `John Doe` and `john doe` respectively, you'd probably put the books by `John Doe` first :)

Comment: But they don't. My double negative in the question may have confused the issue. The lowercase letters have precedence (meaning they are considered less than their uppercase counterparts) - this is the source of my confusion